# Check if Trendline Exists in VBA

Tags: vba, object, exists, trendline

I have a sheet with a chart in it. I need to insert a button to TOGGLE the Trendline On/Off. So first, I need to check whether a trendline exists or not. Sounds simple, but is driving me NUTS!!!

Here is the code that I use to create the trednline and format it:

```
Sub Trending() 

Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).Select
    With Selection
        .Type = xlPolynomial
        .Order = 3
        .Border.ColorIndex = 3
        .Border.Weight = xlMedium

    End With

End Sub
```

To check for the existence of a trendline, I tried:

```
If Sheets("Sheet 1").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollections(1).Trendlines(1).Count = 1 Then
    [Statement]
End If
```

But the test fails.

What am I doing wrong? What is a non-dirty way to do it?

Thanks,
Al

Comment: Have you tried using `Trendlines.Count` instead of trying to index with `Trendlines(1)`?

Comment: From VBA Help: *Use the Trendlines method to return the Trendlines collection. The following example displays the number of trendlines for series one in Chart1.* `MsgBox Charts(1).SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Count`

Comment: I have tried this yes Remnant. Says "Subscript is out of range", even though I do have ONE chart on the sheet, with a trendline active on it. Really frustrating.

Comment: Minor point, but you code has an `s` on the end of `SeriesCollection` and I wonder whether this is a typo that is impacting your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three things wrong with your `If` statement. Had you broken down your statement in smaller bits and tested each of them separately, you would have found that:

1. It's `Sheet1`, not `Sheet 1`. No space. This is what causes your "Subscript is out of range" error.
2. The `SeriesCollection` property applies to `Chart` objects, not `ChartObject` object. Yes, I know this stupid Excel terminology is confusing. Anyhoo, you need `ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)`, not `ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1)`.
3. `Trendlines(1)` returns a `Trendline` object, which is not `Count`able. You want to count the itemts in the trendlines collection, i.e. `Trendlines.Count`, not `Trendlines(1).Count`.

To summarise, this is how to write it:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart _
    .SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "there is exactly one trendline"
End If
```

Note: this will only work if the trendline count is exactly one. Consider replacing `=` with `>=` if there may be more than one.

Comment: Jean-Francois, your comments are very useful, for resolving this problem and for my VBA beginner knowledge in general. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry Jean-Francois, I am new to Stackoverflow. By upvoting, you mean setting that number on the left to "2" rather than "1" (is it kind of a score?). If so, I just did :-) Let me know if this is what you were referring to. You explained well and deserve the upvote.